# Is "Be noticed that..." considered correct in use of an imperative sentence?

Tags: imperative-sentences

If I want to request attention of a [hearer](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hearer), I know that I can create an [imperative sentence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/imperative-sentence) such as:

> **"Be aware that** there are some exceptions."

or

> **"Be note that** there are are some exceptions."

or maybe

> **"Be notice that** there are some exceptions." ([look at this source](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100547/please-note-vs-please-notice))

But my question is about another variants, which is an imperative passive voice:

> ***"Be noticed that*** there are some exceptions."

or

> **"Get noticed that** there are some exceptions."

Well, by googling I found 2 contradictory answers: 
The first one ([here](https://www.italki.com/question/309873)) claims that "Be noticed that..." is wrong, while in other site ([here](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-noticed-get-somebody-noticed)) I found that it's possible to use it. What's correct? and what is your personal experience regarding to that, as native English speakers?

Comment: You could use the present subjunctive only in the case of "noted": it would have to be reworded from yours to read: "Be **it** noted that..." This construction, however, is very formal.

Answer (score 1):

In formal English, you could say "Please be advised that".  You can also say "be aware that", as you noted.  Otherwise, just say "Note that" or "Notice that" (the former meaning "Take note that" and the latter meaning "You should observe that").

> Note that there are some exceptions.

You can't say "be note that", "be noted that" or "be noticed that".  Those are all wrong.  (You could say "it should be noted that ...".)

Comment: He could say it fancily by using the subjunctive here: "Be it noted that..." The rest are wrong, however, so I agree with you, rjpond.